# How can I add/remove rows in ag-Grid?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, ag-grid

I've using [ag-Grid](https://www.ag-grid.com/) with my React - Typescript project I can set data and get selected data from table but I don't know how to add new empty field and how to remove selected field, I've find on its documents but does not found :(

Comment: how you can read from documentation https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-api/index.php you can use setRowData(rows) to set new rows into the grid.

Comment: Ahh I see, I've to use an old data as reference then add new one right or remove right ?

Comment: And when I want to keep data in temporary reference I have to use forEachNode to push to my array

Answer (score 2):

Using setRowData to set rows so when I want to add new empty field I have to do like

```
const allNodesData = Array<any>()
this.gridApi.forEachNode((node) => {
  allNodesData.push(node.data)
})
allNodesData.push({})
this.gridApi.setRowData(allNodesData)
```

And when I want to remove selected field I have to do like

```
const selectedNodes = this.gridApi.getSelectedNodes()
const allNodesData = Array<any>()
this.gridApi.forEachNode((node) => {
  if (selectedNodes.indexOf(node) < 0)
    allNodesData.push(node.data)
})
this.gridApi.setRowData(allNodesData)
```